# Connect different database(Dynamic) in single application in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, database-connection, grails-orm

I have a grails application having version 3.3.+
in before versions like 2.2.1 etc i can connect database on run time with session.reconnect(connect) function (hibernate)
but in new version this line throw exception like 
'Cannot manually reconnect unless Connection was originally supplied by user'

could any one tell me how to connect databases in run time in grails version above 3

Answer (score 0):

Introduced in GORM 6.0, the [ConnectionSources](https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/api/org/grails/datastore/mapping/core/connections/ConnectionSources.html) API allows you to introspect the data sources configured for the application.

Ref: [GORM Docs](https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/#connectionSources)